# NameError: name "df_data" is not defined

Tags: python-3.x, opencsv

[NameError: name "df_data" is not defined](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tYBTO.png)

I'm trying to read CSV files using VSCode and using the Jupyter extension, and it's returning an error stating that "df_data" is not defined, I'm new to this area, I've looked for several articles and videos but I still haven't been able to solve the problem, anyone can you help me please

Comment: The code in the screenshot does not match the code in the error, are you sure you are running  the right code? maybe you did not save it?